# choosing vector elements in a loop based on another vector

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector v1 with 20 elements and another vector indicating groups within that other vector

```
v2=c(3, 10, 7)
```

This means the first group is the 3 first elements of v1, the second group the next 10 elements and finally the last group the last 7 elements.

I using a loop from 1 to 3  (the number of groups)

```
for (j in 1:3)
```

and need to choose the first 3 elements when j=1, the next 10 elements when j=2 and the last 7 when j=3

How could I do this inside the loop?

Comment: What is your expected output? A `list`? A `data.frame`? Something else?

Comment: I just need to use for example the first 3 elements,  so create a temporal vector with those 3 elements when j=1.

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, it gives `split(v1, rep(seq_along(v2), v2))`.